# FullCalendar - How to increase the time in minutes of an event in 'fc-time' with append when user is resizing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I trying to increase the a time in minutes when the user is resizing an event . 
I need to put in the class .fc-time that is the first line . How is the way that i´m doing but doesnt work .

Im using the function eventResize()

```
eventResize(event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
  ....
  const durationEventInMinutes =calcDurationMinutes(event.start,event.end);
$(this).find('fc-time').append(` ( ${durationEventInMinutes} )`);
}
```

If a put a console log in $(this).find('fc-time') i will see that i have change the value of that event . 
He would show like that: 08:00-10:30 (3h30m) 
My function returns that value, but the event doesn't update in .fc-time he doesn't show anything. 
Anyone have handle with this?
What I´m doing wrong? Can anyone help me?

Comment: ".fc-time", not "fc-time". And what is this syntax: `\` ( ${durationEventInMinutes} )\``? surely just `.append(durationEventInMinutes)`? But I tested and even after that it doesn't work. I suspect something in fullCalendar runs _after_ eventResize in order to display the time. not sure at the moment how we get round that.

Comment: I believe in that even I append but when the eventResize finish he changes - And the syntax of $(durationEventInMinutes) is because I use the syntax es6 for concatenation , and i concat '(' + durationEventInMinutes + ')' is the same thing

Comment: ok. But yes after eventResize finishes, something else in fullCalendar overwrites it. That's what I explained already. At the moment I can't think of any workaround. I haven't got time to test now, but does "eventRender" run after "eventResize"? I wonder if it might. If it does, then potentially you can make your change in there instead.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson I find a solution a put my function that calculate de interval in minutes inside eventRender and for what I need its works !